# Failure during analysis, Node.js command to start eslint-bidge server was not built yet Scanning JS in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When I tried to scan a js project using sonarqube it returned this error.
03:55:08.724 ERROR: Failure during analysis, Node.js command to start eslint-bridge server was not built yet. The logs only shows these:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths

               at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

               at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.read(TarArchiveInputStream.java:608)

               at java.base/java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)

               at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:85)

               at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:60)

               at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.BundleImpl.extractFromClasspath(BundleImpl.java:104)

               at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.BundleImpl.deploy(BundleImpl.java:74)

               at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.deploy(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:95)

               at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServerLazily(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:169)

               at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.AbstractEslintSensor.execute(AbstractEslintSensor.java:106)

               at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.execute(JavaScriptEslintBasedSensor.java:49)

               at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)

               at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)

               at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)

               at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)

               at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)

               at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)

               at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)

               at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)

               at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:388)

               at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:384)

               at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:353)

               at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)

               at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)

               at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:144)

               at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)

               at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)

               at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)

               at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)

               at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)

               at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

               at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

               at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

               at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)

               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)

               at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)

               at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)

               at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)

               at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)

               at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

03:55:08.724 INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript] (done) | time=371ms
```

There is nothing else in the logs that is telling me why it fails aside from this and I couldn't understand what this means. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Plugin was corrupted so I had to reinstall the plugin.